# If $ a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|a|^2 - |b|^2 = 1$, then the zeros of $az^{n+1}+bz^n - \overline{b}z - \overline{a} $ lie on the unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I've got absolutely no idea how to approach this problem. I know that if the zeros of a polynomial $p(z)$ lie on the unit circle then $\max |p{'}(z)| = \frac{n}{2} \max|p(z)|$, where $n = deg(p)$. I am not sure the converse is true. Could someone please give a  hint on how to start the solution? My hunch is an easy way to solve it will involve Schwarz's lemma. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
az^{n+1}+bz^n - \overline{b}z - \overline{a} = 0
$$
is equivalent to
$$
 z^n = \frac{\overline{b}z + \overline{a}}{az+b} \, .
$$
Now show that $|z| < 1$ implies $\left|\frac{\overline{b}z + \overline{a}}{az+b} \right| > 1$, and $|z| > 1$ implies $\left|\frac{\overline{b}z + \overline{a}}{az+b} \right| < 1$.

It follows that $|z|=1$ is the only possibility.

In order to show the above implications it is helpful to expand
$$
 |az+b| ^2 - |\overline{b}z + \overline{a}|^2 \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!